# iOS security Framework in xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, xcode4.5

I am using `Xcode 4.5` and the security framework is missing, so I copied the security framework folder from my friend's `Xcode 5` and added in my `Xcode 4.5` framework folder. But I couldn't handle it, so I removed the security.framework folder from frameworks folder.

Now the problem is I am making a simple app where security.framework is not needed and when I make an archive of my application, it's getting an error in `foundation.framework` in `NSURLCredential.h` file. There are these two lines:

```
#import < Foundation/NSObject.h >

#import < Security/Security.h > ------------------ >>> "Security/Security.h" file not found.
```

So I cannot make an archive of my application.

Can anyone please help me about how I can make an archive?

Pardon about my english.

Thanks.

Comment: Easiest thing to do would be reinstall Xcode 4 or 5 cleanly.

Comment: @zeeshanshaikh You're welcome. Try to avoid pressing `enter` in the middle of sentences, before the sentence is over. (: